# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. in production - Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, netlify

I have been getting this error while Deploying my rails project in Netlify.

My setup

- Ubuntu 20.04.2
- Ruby 3.1.2
- Rails 7.0.4
- pg 1.4.3 with native extensions

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
11:15:40 AM:     current directory: /opt/build/cache/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.3/ext
11:15:40 AM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby -I
11:15:40 AM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
11:15:40 AM: ./siteconf20221005-3131-h6mhxz.rb extconf.rb
11:15:40 AM: Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
11:15:40 AM: checking for pg_config... no
11:15:40 AM: checking for libpq per pkg-config... no
11:15:40 AM: Using libpq from
11:15:40 AM: checking for libpq-fe.h... no
11:15:40 AM: Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
11:15:40 AM: *****************************************************************************
11:15:40 AM: Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.
```

Here is the full deploy log (sorry it's a big long)

```
10:51:24 AM: Build ready to start
10:51:33 AM: build-image version: 9289b698a503f132b265bd089ab40ce1d6f9e65e (focal)
10:51:33 AM: build-image tag: v4.12.0
10:51:33 AM: buildbot version: 8004afba0d79c2913deefb1ea0ee8f3ed710b828
10:51:34 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:51:34 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
10:51:34 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:51:34 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:51:34 AM: git clone https://github.com/PaulineTW/quote-editor
10:51:34 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:51:34 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
10:51:35 AM: Starting build script
10:51:35 AM: Installing dependencies
10:51:35 AM: Python version set to 2.7
10:51:36 AM: v16.17.1 is already installed.
10:51:36 AM: Now using node v16.17.1 (npm v8.15.0)
10:51:36 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:51:36 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:51:36 AM: Required ruby-3.1.2 is not installed.
10:51:36 AM: To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-3.1.2"'
10:51:36 AM: Attempting ruby version 3.1.2, read from .ruby-version file
10:51:37 AM: Required ruby-3.1.2 is not installed - installing.
10:51:37 AM: Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
10:51:38 AM: Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/20.04/x86_64/ruby-3.1.2.tar.bz2
10:51:38 AM: Checking requirements for ubuntu.
10:51:38 AM: Requirements installation successful.
10:51:38 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #configure
10:51:38 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #download
10:51:40 AM: No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
10:51:40 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #validate archive
10:51:45 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #extract
10:51:48 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #validate binary
10:51:48 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #setup
10:51:48 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global
10:51:48 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #importing gemset /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems........................................
10:51:49 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #generating global wrappers........
10:51:49 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #gemset created /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2
10:51:49 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #importing gemsetfile /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
10:51:49 AM: ruby-3.1.2 - #generating default wrappers........
10:51:50 AM: Using /opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2
10:51:50 AM: Using ruby version 3.1.2
10:51:50 AM: Using bundler version 2.3.22 from Gemfile.lock
10:51:51 AM: Successfully installed bundler-2.3.22
10:51:51 AM: 1 gem installed
10:51:51 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
10:51:51 AM: Started restoring cached ruby gems
10:51:51 AM: Finished restoring cached ruby gems
10:51:51 AM: Installing gem bundle
10:51:51 AM: [DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local path '/opt/build/cache/bundle'`, and stop using this flag
10:51:51 AM: [DEPRECATED] The --binstubs option will be removed in favor of `bundle binstubs --all`
10:51:52 AM: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
10:51:52 AM: Fetching rake 13.0.6
10:51:53 AM: Installing rake 13.0.6
10:51:53 AM: Using racc 1.6.0
10:51:53 AM: Using digest 3.1.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching timeout 0.3.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching msgpack 1.5.6
10:51:53 AM: Using bundler 2.3.22
10:51:53 AM: Fetching matrix 0.4.2
10:51:53 AM: Fetching regexp_parser 2.6.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching childprocess 4.1.0
10:51:53 AM: Using io-console 0.5.11
10:51:53 AM: Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching rexml 3.2.5
10:51:53 AM: Fetching websocket 1.2.9
10:51:53 AM: Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
10:51:53 AM: Fetching minitest 5.16.3
10:51:53 AM: Fetching builder 3.2.4
10:51:53 AM: Fetching erubi 1.11.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching crass 1.0.6
10:51:53 AM: Fetching rack 2.2.4
10:51:53 AM: Fetching nio4r 2.5.8
10:51:53 AM: Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
10:51:53 AM: Fetching marcel 1.0.2
10:51:53 AM: Fetching mini_mime 1.1.2
10:51:53 AM: Fetching strscan 3.0.4
10:51:53 AM: Fetching public_suffix 5.0.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching bcrypt 3.1.18
10:51:53 AM: Fetching bindex 0.8.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching method_source 1.0.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching thor 1.2.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching zeitwerk 2.6.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching pg 1.4.3
10:51:53 AM: Fetching rubyzip 2.3.2
10:51:53 AM: Fetching redis 4.8.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching nokogiri 1.13.8 (x86_64-linux)
10:51:53 AM: Fetching reline 0.3.1
10:51:53 AM: Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing strscan 3.0.4 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing erubi 1.11.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
10:51:53 AM: Installing timeout 0.3.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing crass 1.0.6
10:51:53 AM: Installing method_source 1.0.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing websocket 1.2.9
10:51:53 AM: Installing bindex 0.8.1 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing matrix 0.4.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing builder 3.2.4
10:51:53 AM: Installing zeitwerk 2.6.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing childprocess 4.1.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing rubyzip 2.3.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing marcel 1.0.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing thor 1.2.1
10:51:53 AM: Installing bcrypt 3.1.18 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing reline 0.3.1
10:51:53 AM: Installing regexp_parser 2.6.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing redis 4.8.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing msgpack 1.5.6 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing minitest 5.16.3
10:51:53 AM: Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.5
10:51:53 AM: Installing rexml 3.2.5
10:51:53 AM: Installing public_suffix 5.0.0
10:51:53 AM: Fetching net-protocol 0.1.3
10:51:53 AM: Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing rack 2.2.4
10:51:53 AM: Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Installing net-protocol 0.1.3
10:51:53 AM: Installing pg 1.4.3 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Fetching mail 2.7.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching net-smtp 0.3.2
10:51:53 AM: Fetching net-pop 0.1.1
10:51:53 AM: Using irb 1.4.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching debug 1.6.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing net-pop 0.1.1
10:51:53 AM: Installing net-smtp 0.3.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
10:51:53 AM: Installing debug 1.6.2 with native extensions
10:51:53 AM: Fetching addressable 2.8.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching selenium-webdriver 4.4.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing mail 2.7.1
10:51:53 AM: Installing addressable 2.8.1
10:51:53 AM: Fetching warden 1.2.9
10:51:53 AM: Fetching rack-test 2.0.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing selenium-webdriver 4.4.0
10:51:53 AM: Installing rack-test 2.0.2
10:51:53 AM: Installing warden 1.2.9
10:51:53 AM: Installing nokogiri 1.13.8 (x86_64-linux)
10:51:54 AM: Fetching sprockets 4.1.1
10:51:54 AM: Fetching tzinfo 2.0.5
10:51:54 AM: Fetching i18n 1.12.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing i18n 1.12.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing tzinfo 2.0.5
10:51:54 AM: Installing sprockets 4.1.1
10:51:54 AM: Fetching activesupport 7.0.4
10:51:54 AM: Installing activesupport 7.0.4
10:51:54 AM: Fetching webdrivers 5.1.0
10:51:54 AM: Fetching loofah 2.19.0
10:51:54 AM: Fetching xpath 3.2.0
10:51:54 AM: Fetching globalid 1.0.0
10:51:54 AM: Fetching activemodel 7.0.4
10:51:54 AM: Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
10:51:54 AM: Installing globalid 1.0.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing xpath 3.2.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
10:51:54 AM: Installing webdrivers 5.1.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing loofah 2.19.0
10:51:54 AM: Installing activemodel 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching activejob 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching capybara 3.37.1
10:51:55 AM: Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
10:51:55 AM: Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.3
10:51:55 AM: Installing activejob 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching actionview 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching activerecord 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Installing capybara 3.37.1
10:51:55 AM: Installing actionview 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Installing activerecord 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching actionpack 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching jbuilder 2.11.5
10:51:55 AM: Installing jbuilder 2.11.5
10:51:55 AM: Installing actionpack 7.0.4
10:51:55 AM: Fetching net-imap 0.2.3
10:51:55 AM: Installing net-imap 0.2.3
10:51:56 AM: Fetching railties 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Fetching simple_form 5.1.0
10:51:56 AM: Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
10:51:56 AM: Fetching actionmailer 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
10:51:56 AM: Installing actionmailer 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Fetching activestorage 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Installing simple_form 5.1.0
10:51:56 AM: Installing railties 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Installing activestorage 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Fetching actiontext 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Fetching actionmailbox 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Installing actionmailbox 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Installing actiontext 7.0.4
10:51:56 AM: Fetching stimulus-rails 1.1.0
10:51:56 AM: Fetching cssbundling-rails 1.1.1
10:51:56 AM: Fetching responders 3.0.1
10:51:56 AM: Fetching turbo-rails 1.3.0
10:51:56 AM: Fetching web-console 4.2.0
10:51:56 AM: Fetching jsbundling-rails 1.0.3
10:51:56 AM: Installing cssbundling-rails 1.1.1
10:51:56 AM: Installing responders 3.0.1
10:51:56 AM: Installing jsbundling-rails 1.0.3
10:51:56 AM: Installing web-console 4.2.0
10:51:56 AM: Installing stimulus-rails 1.1.0
10:51:56 AM: Installing turbo-rails 1.3.0
10:51:56 AM: Fetching devise 4.8.1
10:51:57 AM: Installing devise 4.8.1
10:51:58 AM: Fetching actioncable 7.0.4
10:51:58 AM: Fetching puma 5.6.5
10:51:58 AM: Installing actioncable 7.0.4
10:51:58 AM: Fetching rails 7.0.4
10:51:58 AM: Installing puma 5.6.5 with native extensions
10:51:58 AM: Installing rails 7.0.4
10:51:59 AM: Fetching bootsnap 1.13.0
10:51:59 AM: Installing bootsnap 1.13.0 with native extensions
10:52:01 AM: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
10:52:01 AM:     current directory: /opt/build/cache/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.3/ext
10:52:01 AM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby -I
10:52:01 AM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
10:52:01 AM: ./siteconf20221005-3131-7yd4os.rb extconf.rb
10:52:01 AM: Calling libpq with GVL unlocked
10:52:01 AM: checking for pg_config... no
10:52:01 AM: checking for libpq per pkg-config... no
10:52:01 AM: Using libpq from
10:52:01 AM: checking for libpq-fe.h... no
10:52:01 AM: Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
10:52:01 AM: *****************************************************************************
10:52:01 AM: Unable to find PostgreSQL client library.
10:52:01 AM: Please install libpq or postgresql client package like so:
10:52:01 AM:   sudo apt install libpq-dev
10:52:01 AM:   sudo yum install postgresql-devel
10:52:01 AM:   sudo zypper in postgresql-devel
10:52:01 AM:   sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs
10:52:01 AM: or try again with:
10:52:01 AM:   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
10:52:01 AM: or set library paths manually with:
10:52:01 AM: gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/libpq-fe.h/
10:52:01 AM: --with-pg-lib=/path/to/libpq.so/
10:52:01 AM: *** extconf.rb failed ***
10:52:01 AM: Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
10:52:01 AM: libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
10:52:01 AM: need configuration options.
10:52:01 AM: Provided configuration options:
10:52:01 AM:    --with-opt-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --without-opt-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --with-opt-include
10:52:01 AM:    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
10:52:01 AM:    --with-opt-lib
10:52:01 AM:    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
10:52:01 AM:    --with-make-prog
10:52:01 AM:    --without-make-prog
10:52:01 AM:    --srcdir=.
10:52:01 AM:    --curdir
10:52:01 AM:    --ruby=/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg
10:52:01 AM:    --enable-gvl-unlock
10:52:01 AM:    --disable-gvl-unlock
10:52:01 AM:    --enable-windows-cross
10:52:01 AM:    --disable-windows-cross
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg-config
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg-config
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg_config
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg_config
10:52:01 AM:    --with-libpq-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --without-libpq-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --with-libpq-include
10:52:01 AM:    --without-libpq-include=${libpq-dir}/include
10:52:01 AM:    --with-libpq-lib
10:52:01 AM:    --without-libpq-lib=${libpq-dir}/lib
10:52:01 AM:    --with-libpq-config
10:52:01 AM:    --without-libpq-config
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pkg-config
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pkg-config
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg-dir
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg-include
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
10:52:01 AM:    --with-pg-lib
10:52:01 AM:    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
10:52:01 AM: To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
10:52:01 AM: be found here:
10:52:01 AM: /opt/build/cache/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/pg-1.4.3/mkmf.log
10:52:01 AM: extconf failed, exit code 1
10:52:01 AM: Gem files will remain installed in
10:52:01 AM: /opt/build/cache/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.3 for inspection.
10:52:01 AM: Results logged to
10:52:01 AM: /opt/build/cache/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/pg-1.4.3/gem_make.out
10:52:01 AM: /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in
10:52:01 AM: `run'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in`block in build'  /opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in`build'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in
10:52:01 AM: `build_extension'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in`block in build_extensions'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in
10:52:01 AM: `each'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in`build_extensions'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in
10:52:01 AM: `build_extensions'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in`build_extensions'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
10:52:01 AM: `install'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:207:in`install'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
10:52:01 AM: `install'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in`install_from_spec'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
10:52:01 AM: `do_install'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in`block in worker_pool'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
10:52:01 AM: `apply_func'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in`block in process_queue'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
10:52:01 AM: `loop'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in`process_queue'/opt/buildhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.22/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in
10:52:02 AM: `block (2 levels) in create_threads'An error occurred while installing pg (1.4.3), and Bundler cannot continue.In Gemfile:  pgError during gem install
10:52:02 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:52:02 AM: Creating deploy upload records
10:52:02 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:52:02 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:52:02 AM: Finished processing build request in 28.417567123s
```

i have tried quite a lot of things as per below but always get same error

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpq5
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc-12
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpq-dev libpq5
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 336 not upgraded.
```

```
gem install pg

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.4.3
Parsing documentation for pg-1.4.3
Installing ri documentation for pg-1.4.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config

Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.4.3
Parsing documentation for pg-1.4.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I have tried a lot of suggestions but still can't find a way out. I will really appreciate if somebody could help.

Comment: It looks like Netlity can't host a Rails app, as it is only for Statis Site